# Subscription receipt validation giving wrong product_id and expires_date on Restore

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, subscription, storekit, receipt-validation

I am working on receipt validation for an auto-renew subscription. Running into a big issue when it comes to restoring. Restoring seems to be restoring an old transaction with a different product_id, thus marking my UI as expired.

**Purchasing works fine.**

Here's the JSON response when I make a purchase:

```
LAST RECEIPT INFORMATION: 
 {
    "expires_date" = "2019-01-20 18:29:02 Etc/GMT";
    "expires_date_ms" = 1548008942000;
    "expires_date_pst" = "2019-01-20 10:29:02 America/Los_Angeles";
    "is_in_intro_offer_period" = false;
    "is_trial_period" = false;
    "original_purchase_date" = "2019-01-20 18:26:03 Etc/GMT";
    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1548008763000;
    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2019-01-20 10:26:03 America/Los_Angeles";
    "original_transaction_id" = 1000000484645981;
    "product_id" = "com.mywebsite.weekly"; // The CORRECT product_id of what I am purchasing in sandbox.
    "purchase_date" = "2019-01-20 18:26:02 Etc/GMT";
    "purchase_date_ms" = 1548008762000;
    "purchase_date_pst" = "2019-01-20 10:26:02 America/Los_Angeles";
    quantity = 1;
    "transaction_id" = 1000000495942050;
    "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000042313304;
}

   - DATE BOUGHT SUBSCRIPTION = 2019-01-20 18:26:03 +0000


   - DATE SUBSCRIPTION EXPIRES = 2019-01-20 18:29:02 +0000
```

You can see that the difference between `"original_purchase_date" = "2019-01-20 18:26:03 Etc/GMT";` and `"expires_date" = "2019-01-20 18:29:02 Etc/GMT";` is 3 minutes, as it should be in sandbox for a week-long subscription.

Now comes the problem..
When I restore, **OR** when I re-purchase the same product (and prompted that I'm already subscribed to it by StoreKit), I get a completely different `product_id` and `expires_date`:

```
LAST RECEIPT INFORMATION: 
 {
    "expires_date" = "2019-01-17 16:47:19 Etc/GMT";
    "expires_date_ms" = 1547743639000;
    "expires_date_pst" = "2019-01-17 08:47:19 America/Los_Angeles";
    "is_in_intro_offer_period" = false;
    "is_trial_period" = false;
    "original_purchase_date" = "2019-01-20 18:38:59 Etc/GMT";
    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1548009539000;
    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2019-01-20 10:38:59 America/Los_Angeles";
    "original_transaction_id" = 1000000495390111;
    "product_id" = "com.mywebsite.group2.weekly2"; // WRONG product_id
    "purchase_date" = "2019-01-17 16:44:19 Etc/GMT";
    "purchase_date_ms" = 1547743459000;
    "purchase_date_pst" = "2019-01-17 08:44:19 America/Los_Angeles";
    quantity = 1;
    "transaction_id" = 1000000495942766;
    "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000042278610;
}

   - DATE BOUGHT SUBSCRIPTION = 2019-01-20 18:38:59 +0000 // This is the time that I "re-bought" the product and StoreKit told me I'm already subscribed.)


   - DATE SUBSCRIPTION EXPIRES = 2019-01-17 16:47:19 +0000 // This is the completely wrong date.
```

Here's the portion of my receipt validator that I'm getting the purchased/expiration:

```
if let receiptInfo: NSArray = appReceiptJSON!["latest_receipt_info"] as? NSArray {
    let lastReceipt = receiptInfo.lastObject as! NSDictionary

    // Get last receipt
    print("\nLAST RECEIPT INFORMATION: \n", lastReceipt)

    // Format date
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale

    // Get "original_purchase_date" as NSDate
    let subscriptionBoughtDate: NSDate = formatter.date(from: lastReceipt["original_purchase_date"] as! String)! as NSDate
    print("\n   - DATE BOUGHT SUBSCRIPTION = \(subscriptionBoughtDate)\n")

    // Get "expires_date" as NSDate
    let subscriptionExpirationDate: NSDate = formatter.date(from: lastReceipt["expires_date"] as! String)! as NSDate
    print("\n   - DATE SUBSCRIPTION EXPIRES = \(subscriptionExpirationDate)\n")

    // Save the expiration date.
    // ...
    // Done saving the expiration date.
}
```

**Why is Restore / Re-purchase giving me a completely wrong product_id and expiry date, while the initial purchase works just fine?**

If needed, I can post more code to help debugging this bizarre issue. Just let me know what you'd like to see.

Comment: Had this sandbox user ever purchased `com.mywebsite.group2.weekly2` or did they only purchase `com.mywebsite.weekly`? I'm 90% sure this is a sandbox issue and is related to the fact that you can't upgrade/downgrade subscriptions in sandbox.

Comment: @enc_life - Yes. This sandbox user purchased com.mywebsite.group2.weekly2. I'm using the same bundle identifier for several test projects to test multiple ways of implementing IAP's and subscriptions. Additionally, I use the same sandbox user throughout these projects.

Comment: Receipts are tied to the user account and the bundle Id. Since there aren't installation receipts in sandbox, it's very likely that this is an issue where a different receipt is being accessed on restore from a previous purchase somewhere else. I'd try a new sanbox user and only make/restore purchases for that user in a single app.

Comment: @enc_life I actually did just that shortly after making this post! I wanted a "clean slate" for testing. So far, no issues at all! But I'm just wondering, with this "dirty" sandbox user that was used for on multiple projects & multiple product_id, why I'm able to successfully purchase a subscription, but when it comes down to restoring it, the receipt gives me something completely different? (as shown in the JSON response above)

Comment: I've ran into so many undocumented nuances with sandbox it's hard to know the exact behavior without a lot of testing. My guess is it has something to do with 1) no receipt upon installation for sandbox and 2) receipts contain the entire transaction history for the subscription group.